# A search box for all sites - Multisite

Tags: categories, multisite, search

I have setup a few websites with `Multisite`. I have different topics in my website. Therefore, i have created `topic1.mysite.com`, `topic2.mysite.com`, `topic3.mysite.com`

Let me explain how the look i want for the search form. The search form that I wanted to create is to allow users to search the content they want with the topic in my website.

The search form that i want is to have 2 fields. 1st field is to search the post content. And the 2nd field is to let users to select which topic they want to go for. Here is the link to the attachment`(describe the look of the searchbox)`. --> http://www.ncc.my/img/multisite-searchbox-look.jpg. I can only share the image this way as i don't have ability to post the image here directly dues to my reputation issue.

The usage of the search form is after they have enter the search keyword, if they choose the `topic2` is the 2nd field, they will be redirect to the `search result` page of the `topic2` which is `topic2.mysite.com`

Is this possible? Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible. You can use [`wp_get_sites()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites) to get a list of sites to populate your dropdown, and either use a [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)/[`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) pairing to grab content from the appropriate site, or else [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to redirect to the search results page in the relevant site.

Comment: Hi @PatJ, ! I do not know how to implement this to the search box. Would you please provide instruction how to make it work? A tutorial is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What *exact* issue are you running into? Note that Stack Exchange is not a "do my work for me" site; if you need significant development assistance, you might need to hire someone. If you haven't already, you may want to have a look at [the WPSE tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I didn't think that Stack Exchange is a "do my work for me" site. Was just no idea how to do it. That's why i would be great if there is a tutorial for me to learn.

Comment: @PatJ, i tried to put `<?php echo wp_get_sites(); ?>` to my site, but result turns out to say "Array". If i remove the `echo`, then it shows nothing. I don't get the dropdown list as you mentioned. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @PatJ, i found solution for my question from somewhere else. If you have written your answer in an `Answer`, then i shall be able to vote you up. :)

Comment: Since you got it working, you can post an **Answer** of your own, detailing what you did to make it work. After a short time (I believe it's 48 hours), you can mark your answer **Accepted**, which will help others who want to accomplish the same sort of thing.

Comment: @PatJ, sure! Will do it soon. Would love to share it out to others. Your comment helped me as you told me it's possible. Therefore, I keep searching over and over again. Finally I got this solution. By the way, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. (Here I was thinking I'd been distinctly less than helpful. Glad to have pointed you in the right direction, at least.)